Symmetry transformations in C* formulation in quantum mechanics
In the normal Hilbert space formulation of quantum mechanics, symmetry transformations are represented by unitary (or antiuntitary) operators that act on a Hilbert space. So my question is: How can symmetry transformations be realized in the $C^*$ formulation in quantum mechanics? Do they affect the algebraic structure? If you have a state
$$\rho:\mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{C}$$ how is it affected by the symmetry transformation? Especially time evolution would be important to analyse how states evolve in time.

What is $\mathcal A$?

@Mauricio $\mathcal{A}$ is the $C^*$ Algebra representing the physical system.

Do you want a definition, or what? Have you checked a book on that topic?
